# Python regular expression to match a path

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex to match a library in a file and the path containingg the file. All the libraries in the file will be in the format.

```
text = "mylib|C://desktop//baseicmylib.lib
        randlib|C://desktop//randlib.lib"
```

so if I want to find mylib

I wrote

```
str = "mylib"
pattern = r'%s\\|.*lib'%str
mypath = re.findall(pattern,text)
```

Can some one help me where I am making a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's maybe no regex needed?

```
text = '''mylib|C://desktop//baseicmylib.lib
    randlib|C://desktop//randlib.lib'''

libs = dict(line.split('|', 1) for line in
    (s.strip() for s in text.split('\n')))
```

result:

```
{'randlib': 'C://desktop//randlib.lib',
   'mylib': 'C://desktop//baseicmylib.lib'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The // before the pipe is causing the issue.
The following works for me just fine:

```
text = "argh|foo.lib"
str = "argh"
pattern = r"%s\|.*lib" %str
print re.findall(pattern,text)

['argh', '|hehe.lib']
```

// isnt used for escaping, if you had wanted to escape within a raw string a single \ would suffice (and double \ for a non raw string)

Comment: '|' needs to be escaped. In your case its giving the wrong output. Its matching the lib and its matching the path because of or operator

Comment: then backslash is the escape character and not forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

Need to tweak your pattern a little bit:

```
text = '''mylib|C://desktop//baseicmylib.lib
randlib|C://desktop//randlib.lib'''
str = 'mylib'
pattern = "%s\|(.+?\.lib)" %str
print re.findall(pattern,text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>pattern = r'%s.*?lib'%str
>>>re.findall(pattern, text)
['mylib|C://desktop//baseicmylib']
```

It is a [no-greedy](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) match in regex

> *?, +?, ??
>
> The `'*'`, `'+'`, and `'?'` qualifiers are all greedy they match as much text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE `<.*>` is matched against 'title', it will match the entire string, and not just ''. Adding '?' after the qualifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible will be matched. Using .*? in the previous expression will match only ''.